# Why can't I see this div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has the following markup:

```
<div role="gridcell" title="707676" style="width: 84px;" class="grid-cell">707676</div>
```

If I select it in the inspector in Edge or Firefox I can see where it is, but I can't see it's contents.  Can you tell me why?  Here's the CSS:

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0 0 0 0;
border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
border-image-slice: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1 1 1 1;
border-left-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
cursor: default;
display: block;
floatleftfont-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
font-size: 13px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 17px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-bottom: 7px;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-right: 4px;
padding-top: 6px;
position: relative;
text-alignlefttext-overflow: ellipsis;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 84px;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
-moz-user-focus: ignore;
```

I took the real page and simplified it to the following.  It's kind of different than the original markup, especially in how the css is applied, but it seems to reproduce the problem.  Can anyone tell me why I don't see 707676 on my page?  I'm viewing the below example if Firefox.  The real page displays the same behavior in Edge and Firefox.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test of element that's not visible</title>
    <style>
        div {
            border-bottom-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
            border-bottom-style: none;
            border-bottom-width: 0px;
            border-image-outset: 0 0 0 0;
            border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
            border-image-slice: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
            border-image-source: none;
            border-image-width: 1 1 1 1;
            border-left-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
            border-left-style: none;
            border-left-width: 0px;
            border-right-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
            border-right-style: none;
            border-right-width: 0px;
            border-top-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
            border-top-style: none;
            border-top-width: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
            cursor: default;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            font-family: "-apple-system", BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
            font-size: 13px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 17px;
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            padding-left: 4px;
            padding-right: 4px;
            padding-top: 6px;
            position: relative;
            horizonal-align: left;
            text-align:left;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            vertical-align: middle;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 84px;
            -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
            -moz-border-left-colors: none;
            -moz-border-right-colors: none;
            -moz-border-top-colors: none;
            -moz-user-focus: ignore;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div aria-activedescendant="row_60_8" role="grid" tabindex="0" class="grid-canvas ui-draggable">
        <div style="top: 256px; left: 20px; height: 32px; width: 1867px; -moz-user-focus: ignore;" role="row" id="row_60_8">
            <div role="gridcell" title="707676" style="width: 84px;" class="grid-cell">707676</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `floatleftfont-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
` should be `float: left; font-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";`

Comment: Am I missing something or I actually can see it? :|

Comment: @ClydeLobo why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Soviut : done. Also added one more error

Comment: It's weird, I made a simple webpage with just that div and that css and it displays in Firefox.  I'll play with it some more.

Comment: I've tweaked my simple webpage and it now reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Added after the code was simplified**

I found the issue, you have given `position: relative` to parent `div` with `height:30px` and `overflow:hidden`. The 2nd `div` in your HTML has a `top: 256px` which displaces it by `256px` relative to its actual position. As the parent `div` has a fixed height and no overflow, the `div` is hidden and not visible. Try changing the value of top to something less than `30px` and you can see it.

Since I mentioned the error in a comment to the question, posting it as an answer

```
floatleftfont-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

should be

```
float: left; font-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

Also

`text-alignlefttext-overflow: ellipsis;`

Should be

`text-align:left; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: I added a revised example that isn't visible in any browser I've tried.  Although it is admittedly different than the original markup.

Answer (score 5):

You've combined two lines into one.

```
floatleftfont-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

Should be:

```
float: left;
font-family: "-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Ubuntu,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine and is visible in Chrome and Firefox without issue. I am running a Mac so unable to test in Edge for you. There must be something else in your page that is causing it to not be visible.

```
<div role="gridcell" title="707676" style="width: 84px;" class="grid-cell">707676</div>
```

[CodePen Example code](http://codepen.io/dantuck/pen/jrxxGm)